# Grab the textfield data from another stateful widget class

Tags: flutter

I am trying to view the textfield data from another class by accessing the state class's method. I want to get the textfield value in another class when i click a button.

I tried calling the method which should return a string but i don't get any value when i try to access it from the other class.

```
class TitleWidget extends StatefulWidget{
  final IncidentComponent data;
  String titleVal;
  TitleWidget(this.data);
  @override
  TitleWidgetState createState() => TitleWidgetState();
}

class TitleWidgetState extends State<TitleWidget>{

  final titleController = TextEditingController();

  titleTextValue() {
    print("title text field: ${titleController.text}");
    return titleController.text;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    titleController.addListener(titleTextValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  TextField(
      controller: titleController);

  }
}
```

I tried to access the above method to get the string in another class.

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
   label: Text("Complete Report",
   onPressed: () { print('title is ' + TitleWidgetState().titleTextValue()); }
)
```

I was expecting the textfield value when ever i press the FAB button from the other class. But i get nothing from the other class method.
But the titleTextValue() method's print statement prints the right value of the textfield.

Comment: Try it: [break a form into multiple widget and interact with those widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940847/3680374)

Comment: check my answer here as well if you want to try [using Singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940426/break-a-form-into-multiple-widget-and-interact-with-those-widget-in-flutter/56943025#56943025)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this global store. It can save tons of work on passing all kind of objects. Eventually you need to master blocs.

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            new MyStatefulWidget1(),
            new MyStatefulWidget2(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget1 extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new MyStatefulWidget1State();
}

class MyStatefulWidget1State extends State<MyStatefulWidget1> {
  final titleController = TextEditingController();

  titleTextValue() {
    print("title text field: ${titleController.text}");
    return titleController.text;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    store.set("titleTextValue", titleTextValue);
    return TextField(controller: titleController);
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  State createState() => new MyStatefulWidget2State();
}

class MyStatefulWidget2State extends State<MyStatefulWidget2> {
  String _text = 'PRESS ME';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var titleTextValue = store.get("titleTextValue");
    return new Center(
      child: new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(_text),
          onPressed: () {
            print('title is ' + titleTextValue());
          }),
    );
  }
}

class GlobalState {
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> _data = <dynamic, dynamic>{};

  static GlobalState instance = GlobalState._();
  GlobalState._();

  set(dynamic key, dynamic value) => _data[key] = value;
  get(dynamic key) => _data[key];
}

final GlobalState store = GlobalState.instance;
```

Comment: This worked for me, will look into BLOC. Thanks.
I put the line - store.set("titleTextValue", titleTextValue); inside the method titleTextValue() as the build will only run once and returned the text from the textfield using the controller. Like - store.set("titleTextValue", titleController.text);

Comment: Your answer got me thinking that i can use shared preferences too. I can create a preference and then remove or delete the preference too when the widget is created - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value

Comment: Indeed, you can save preferences in SharedPreferences, just remember to test the correct serialization of what you save.

Comment: I save File types (images) using your above answer. Thanks :)